# MVC vs REST/React in terms architecture

Tags: rest, model-view-controller, design-patterns, architecture, terminology

Sorry, if it's kind of newb question. Please, help me to correctly name the architectures I described below.

Lets take we had web-application built with Spring framework/Hibernate/Thymeleaf(or another template engine) with the code of controllers looked like:

```java
@Controller
public class AboutController {
    @GetMapping("/about")
    public String aboutview (Model model) {
        return "about";
    }
```

So, this is pure MVC software design pattern, as I take.

After this we switched from Thymeleaf to ReactJS for UI. So colleagues asked me to make few REST endpoints, which was used later for drawing single React's page. To be more concrete, let's take this controllers produced a filtered list of the users and goods, which was gotten from the JPA Repository.

**So, the questions are:**

1. To which architectural pattern did we switched off instead of pure MVC in above mentioned sample?
2. If it wasn't HMVC (hierarchical MVC), how it supposed to be looked like in term of controllers? Is it should look like few REST-controllers, which calls each other or simultaneously being called from React?
3. If I have few microservices, which has endpoints being called from the one React's page (or whatsoever JS framework), how can I correctly name an architecture of the Application: "microservice app with MVC pattern?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Architecture of a software system is about what components exists in the system, how its components arranged. Of all the components, some of them will be in the same process communicating through function calls. Some of them will be in the same computer but running in different processes. (In this case, they will talk through OS provided inter-process communication). Finally, Some of them will be running in different computers of a network. (For instance; internet) [In this case, they will talk over a network through network protocols(for instance; http) using sockets]

Spring regular MVC or Spring REST Controllers are all about how the VIEW component and the component providing access to system functionality talk to each other and what computer VIEW and component providing access to system functionality runs in.

There might might be many more components which VIEW does not know about because of the fact that VIEW is isolated from other components through back-end API. (This is true for both classic MVC and REST controllers)

For instance; classic MVC or REST controllers might be run against a database or a file and that would not effect the VIEW. There might be a KAFKA broker and that would not effect the VIEW. (In terms of functionality).

When you write your back-end using REST API, mobile applications and other applications can consume that API. Classic MVC can only be consumed by a browser.